# How to get the total lines of a file before it's loaded into a buffer?

Tags: neovim, command-line, buffers

As title.

- My target is to disable a plugin before it is applied to a buffer that will be loaded with the content of a file.
- I can get the file name before it is loaded.
- The file to be opened is assumed to be very large. (>1MB)
- What's the recommended way to do this? Is there any API for this (considering the performance) or should I use some terminal program to get it?

If any info. is missing please let me know.

Comment: What does "loaded" means to you?

Comment: @romainl: I meant before the content of a file is loaded into a buffer. I probably misused the term. Just updated the title.

Comment: I think you are looking for `:help BufReadCmd` in combination with `:help file-functions`.

Comment: Judging from your question, you actually don't want it "before loaded"; you want it "before some specific  autocommand". Then you should figure which one exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the total lines of a file [...]

This can be done in many ways in Neovim and/or Lua (based on the tags you used):

1. You can use the Lua API `io.popen(str_term_cmd):read(...)` to read the output of the command `str_term_cmd`.
2. You can use the Neovim port of Vim's built-in API `vim.fn.system()`. I will prefer this way since:

   1. `If {cmd} is a List it runs directly (no 'shell')`, from the docs.
   2. Some extra checks are done by Bram: `Result is a String, filtered to avoid platform-specific quirks`, from the docs.
   3. This way is more "Vim". And you can avoid the need to `:close()` the file handle.

Remember to turn the `output` into a number. Here is an example usage:

```lua
tonumber(vim.fn.system({ 'wc', '-l', vim.fn.expand('%') }):match('%d+')) > 1000
```

> [...] before it's loaded into a buffer?

If that plugin does provide a callback then you just do the calculation there. Otherwise, you should take a look at `BufReadPre`, `FileReadPre`, `:help BufReadCmd`, `:help file-functions`, as others have suggested.

Comment: very interesting. bookmarked.